# How can we make line by line execution in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, execution

When we need to check the values of parameter at the execution time, specially using the loops. How can we check them?

Comment: There's a debug option. Have you at least searched for it on the net?

Comment: What you are talking about is called `Debugging`. You have an option for that in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't understand how anybody can vote this to close for not providing a SSCCE.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'd VTC for another reason.

Comment: Check the original grammar. Looks like rishie knows english as an extra language. It's obvious rishie just doesn't know the right keyword to get what he wants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the debugger. Start the program in debug mode with <kbd>F11</kbd> after adding breakpoints or identifying where you want to pause the program manually.

When you want to enter the debugger, switch into the "debug" perspective, and hit the "pause" button on the debug toolbar to pause execution.

On the upper right pane you can see your list of objects and references, and explore each as needed, within each thread that is paused at that moment.

Let's see a screenshot:

[image]